# Having trouble importing 'pictures' folder in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a pictures folder inside of my src that I am trying to import so I can use it..

Here is the file structure: [image: structure]

Inside the pictures folder, I have a images.js where I define some imports and exports (because eventually, the folder will contain 50+ pictures in it. The entire code for the picture.js is this:

```
import onionRings from './onionRings.jpg';

export default { onionRings};
```

Then, inside of ExpandedView.js, I am trying to import them but it is giving me a "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pictures' in my project directory. Importing CSS files or other JS files work fine..

Here is the one-line import code I am using in ExpandedView.js: `import * as images from './pictures';`

I have tried moving the pictures folder to other locations but that has not solved it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```js
import * as images from './pictures/images';
```

[See export examples on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#examples)

Comment: That worked! Had to remove the 'default' from the export line of code in addition to that.